# Adding rows searching similar fields

Tags: sql, database

the data is getting logged in the below format .

```
 name                count

'EB4_1F_N_MAIN_IN'
'EB4_1F_N_MOD4_IN'
'EB4_1F_N_MOD5_IN'
'EB4_1F_S_MAIN_IN'
'EB4_2F_N_MAIN_IN'
'EB4_2F_S_MAIN_IN'
'EB4_3F_N_MAIN_IN'
'EB4_3F_S_MAIN_IN'
'EB4_3F_SE_TRN_IN'
'EB4_4F_N_MAIN_IN'
'EB4_4F_S_MAIN_IN'
'EB4_4FSE_TRUN_IN'
'EB4_5F_S_MAIN_IN'
'EB4_GF_N_MAIN_IN'
'EB4_GF_S_MAIN_IN'
'EB5_1F_N_MAIN_IN'
'EB5_1F_S_MAIN_IN'
'EB5_2F_N_MAIN_IN'
'EB5_2F_S_MAIN_IN'
'EB5_2F_SW_DMZ_IN'
'EB5_3F_N_MAIN_IN'
'EB5_3F_S_MAIN_IN'
'EB5_4F_N_MAIN_IN'
'EB5_4F_S_MAIN_IN'
'EB5_5F_N_MAIN_IN'
'EB5_5F_S_MAIN_IN'
'EB5_6F_N_MAIN_IN'
'EB5_6F_S_MAIN_IN'
'EB5_DC_EPX_ST_IN'
'EB5_DC_FM_RM1_IN'
'EB5_DC_FM_RM2_IN'
'EB5_DC_NEPAHU_IN'
'EB5_DC_NWPAHU_IN'
'EB5_DC_SO_NWE_IN'
'EB5_GF_N_MAIN_IN'
'EB6_1F_N_MAIN_IN'
'EB6_1F_S_MAIN_IN'
'EB6_1F_SW_ODC_IN'
'EB6_2F_N_MAIN_IN'
'EB6_2F_S_MAIN_IN'
'EB6_3F_N_MAIN_IN'
'EB6_3F_S_MAIN_IN'
'EB6_4F_N_MAIN_IN'
'EB6_4F_S_MAIN_IN'
'EB6_5F_CISCOMAIN'
'EB6_5F_N_MAIN_IN'
'EB6_5F_S_MAIN_IN'
'EB6_GF_N_MAIN_IN'
'EB6_GF_S_MAIN_IN'
```

Above is the snapshot of the table . count is not shown .My requirement is to add the count of similar names field like adding all 1F_N and similarly .
can u please tell me how do i do this .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is what you are looking for? I tested using SQL Server as you didn't specify what DBMS you are using. Also you didn't define how you determine similarity... I'm used the four char substring starting at 6 in this query, but it should be easily adapted to suit your needs.

```
SELECT a.name, 
       b.cnt AS Count 
FROM   table1 a 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Substring(name, 6, 4) AS substr, 
                          Count(*)              AS cnt 
                   FROM   table1 
                   GROUP  BY Substring(name, 6, 4)) b 
               ON Substring(a.name, 6, 4) = b.substr
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/84204/7)